# Are there big implications of Poincare conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I was just curious: are there any big corollaries of Poincare conjecture in dimension $3$? Is it useful to prove some other (big) theorems? Or is it just a nice statement, and its main value is that whyle trying to prove it, people developed a lot of machinery and important theory?

Comment: In what way have Google failed to satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: Are you referring to the Poincare Conjecture in dimension 3 only? Arguably it has been more useful in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

There's been a lot of work done on classifying manifolds up to homeomorphism, diffeomorphism, homotopy equivalence, etc. The basic question is whether a homotopy sphere in dimension $n$ is actually "equivalent" to $S^n$. I put "equivalent" in quotes because there are many different categories in which you ask the question: smooth, topological, PL, etc. More or less, dimensions $1$ and $2$ are trivial; dimension $4$ is weird (see, for example, Freedman's theorem and Rokhlin's theorem for examples of what the results look like, and look at the status of the smooth Poincare conjecture in dimension $4$); and the case of dimension $\geq 5$ is accessible by surgery methods. (I'm glossing over a huge amount here, so take the previous sentence with a healthy amount of salt.) Dimension $3$ is more geometric than algebraic, though, and required special treatment. The point is that the tools that went into proving the Poincare conjecture are themselves very significant. More generally, Perelman proved the Poincare conjecture as part of Thurston's geometrization conjecture, which gives a nice and useful classification of closed $3$-manifolds.

Comment: One more thing: The version of Poincare's theorem in dimensions $5$ and above is an immediate corollary of the h-cobordism theorem, which is incredibly important on its own. It also holds in dimension $4$, but here you only get a homeomorphism rather than a diffeomorphism from the h-cobordism theorem. The 3-dimensional situation is completely different; there's no equivalent of the h-cobordism theorem (and it requires a bit of care even in dimension $4$).

Comment: Why should there be no h-cobordism theorem in dimension three? There is one and it is even equivalent to the three dimensional Poincaré conjecture. The category of manifolds does not play a role, because they all coincide in dimension three.

Comment: Indeed, there is a even the s-cobordism theorem in dimension 3: It is a combination of the Poincare conjecture and and old theorem of John Stallings from 1960s. However, unlike in higher dimensions, one does not prove the Poincare conjecture using h-cobordism theorem but it is the other way around.

Comment: That's a good point. I meant that the usual h- and s-cobordism proofs using the Whitney trick fail, and so they aren't helpful in proving the Poincare conjecture.